# What are `*.mgd.php` files for?

Tags: extension, php, civicrm-entity, civix, entity-reference

Browsing through a `civix` generated file I see it globbing for `*.mgd.php` files?

What are these files all about then??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So a little research takes me to [Totten's blog](https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/api-and-art-installation) where he lays out the rational for splitting out entity definitions into seperate PHP files.

The full definition of the array format is laid out in the [`hook_civicrm_managed` guide](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_managed) and an example [`.mgd.php` file is here](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.extendedreport/blob/master/CRM/Extendedreport/Form/Report/Price/Lineitem.mgd.php)